# Display the result column name from COALESCE result using SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone help me with the below query update the RESULTANT COLUMN NAME EG:A OR B OR C after using the COALESCE function?

Example:

Table:

```
A - null,
B - null,
C - 5

select COALESCE(A,B,C) As [COL1], [COL2]
from TABLE
```

In this case [Col2] should display the column name as 'C'

Result:

```
[COl1] = 5
[Col2] = C   (Displays the Column Name)
```

Thanks,
Kavin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `case`:

```
select coalesce(A, B, C) As [COL1],
       (case when A is not null then 'A'
             when B is not null then 'B'
             when C is not null then 'C'
        end) as [COL2]
from TABLE;
```

If you wanted to be fancy, you could use `APPLY`:

```
select v.val, v.col
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) v.*
      from (values (t.A, 'A', 1), (t.B, 'B', 2), (t.C, 'C', 3)
           ) v(val, col, ord)
      where val is not null
      order by ord
     ) tt;
```